# Como preencher uma LinkedList (Listas encadeadas) no Python através das entradas do usuário (input)?

Tags: python, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tentando aplicar o conceito de **listas encadeadas no Python** de uma forma que o usuário digita o valor de entrada e assim, é criado em memória o conteúdo sequencialmente. Enquanto o usuário não sair do laço ele poderá preencher um valor de cada vez que irá compor a lista.

```
class No:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
        self.proximo = None

    def mostra_no(self):
        print(self.valor)

class ListaEncadeada:
    def __init__(self):
        self.primeiro = None

    def insere_inicio(self, valor):
        novo = No(valor)
        novo.proximo = self.primeiro
        self.primeiro = novo

    def mostrar(self):
        atual = self.primeiro

        while atual != None:
            atual.mostra_no()
            atual = atual.proximo      
   

entrada = str(input('Digite o nome do voo de Origem : '))
lista = ListaEncadeada()
lista.insere_inicio(entrada)
lista.mostrar()
```

Fiz este exemplo no google Colab e até este ponto deu certo, tentei iterar com um while mas como se trata de um objeto é impossível a iteração. Procurei em exemplos no youtube mas não encontrei nada que utilizasse uma iteração. como resolver ?

Comment: Se a negativação for por uma questão de falta de domínio mínimo da linguagem, peço com todo respeito que me indique um link onde eu possa estudar o assunto, porque até o momento não encontrei nada a respeito e quando procuro no google pelo assunto, é o link da minha pergunta que aparece em primeiro lugar.

Comment: Se entendi direito, seria apenas algo como `while True: ler input, if inválido: break else: insere na lista` - aproveitando, `input` retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário (apenas `input` é o suficiente para obter a string)

Comment: Realmente @hkotsubo é redundante.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Estou postando aqui outro exemplo parecido com o do enunciado, o que eu procurava era uma forma de percorrer a lista. Como estou fazendo este estudo de forma autodidata, eu tive que rever o assunto, e neste caso, não teria como iterar algo que está em um endereço de memória. Compreendi que teria que iniciar com uma referência que no exemplo abaixo é descrito como cabeça da lista.

```
class No:
def __init__(self, valor):
    self.valor = valor
    self.proximo = None 

def mostra_no(self):
    print(self.valor)

    
class listaEncadeada:
def __init__(self):
    self.primeiro = None

def insere_inicio(self, valor):
    novo = No(valor)
    novo.proximo = self.primeiro
    self.primeiro = novo  

def mostrar(self):
    if self.primeiro == None:
        print('Não existem voos cadastrados')
        return None

    atual = self.primeiro
    while atual != None:
        atual.mostra_no()
        atual = atual.proximo

def pesquisa(self, valor):
    if self.primeiro == None:
        print('Não existem voos cadastrados')
        return None

    atual = self.primeiro
    while atual.valor != valor:
        if atual.proximo == None:
            print('Voo não encontrado!')
            break
        else:
            atual = atual.proximo    
    return atual  

lista = listaEncadeada()  

des = int(input('Digite o número de destino da viagem : '))
lista.insere_inicio(des)

pto = 1
while pto != 0:
pto = int(input('Digite um ponto de parada ou zero(0) para informar a origem : '))
if pto != 0:
    lista.insere_inicio(pto)

ori = int(input('Digite a origem do embarque : '))
lista.insere_inicio(ori)

print('')
print('Itinerário da Origem ao Destino da viagem : ')
lista.mostrar()


pesquisa = str(input('Deseja pesquisar por número de voo ?(s/n) : '))
while pesquisa.upper() == 'S':
    aux = int(input('Digite o número do voo : ')) 
    consultar = lista.pesquisa(aux)
    print('Voo nº ', consultar.valor, ' encontrado!')
    pesquisa = str(input('Deseja pesquisar por número de voo ?(s/n) : '))
else:
    print('FIM DA EXECUÇÃO DO PROGRAMA !')
```

Minha dificuldade era: como preencher esta lista encadeada através das entradas que o usuário faria e recuperar esses dados para mostrar na tela. Portanto, a minha dúvida foi resolvida.